Get resolution of pictures in Word file with VBA
I have a question that I was not able to get answered after last hour of internet search.
I need to loop over all figures in a document and check resolution to see if it at least, say 600 dpi.
I created an image with illustrator setting dpi = 1000 and size of 70 x 40 mm. As expected the image is 2756 x 1575 pixels.
I imported then the picture in word. It is correctly sized as 70x40 mm. If I save the picture from word with “save figure as” I get my original size of 2756x1575 pixels.
I run the following code:
Sub GetImageResolutions()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim shape As InlineShape
    Dim resolution As String
    Dim dpi As Double
    Dim width, height As Integer
    
    Debug.Print "Number of images: " & ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
        Set shape = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i)
        If shape.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
            ' Determining original width before scaling
            width = shape.width / shape.ScaleWidth * 100
            height = shape.height / shape.ScaleHeight * 100
            ppi = width / (shape.width / 96)
            Debug.Print "Image " & i & ": "
            Debug.Print shape.width & "x" & shape.height & " points, " & shape.width / 72 * 96 & "x" & shape.height / 72 * 96 & " - " & shape.ScaleWidth & " " & shape.ScaleHeight
            Debug.Print width & " x " & height & " points (scaled)"
            Debug.Print PointsToPixels(width, False) & " x " & PointsToPixels(height, True) & " pixels"
            Debug.Print "resolution: " & ppi
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

What I obtained is odd:
Image 1:
198,35x113,45 points, 264,4667x151,2667 - 100 100
198,35 x 113 points (scaled)
264 x 150 pixels
resolution: 96

Width and Height are given in points (so 72 points in 1 inch). With PointsToPixels there is the transformation that I manually did * 72/96.
Basically it seems that the size in "pixels" given by Word is compatible with the actual size (70x40 mm with a resolution of 96). Indeed the final result (for all images I tested) is always 96.
Am I missing something? I would expect to get 2756 x 1575 px or at least a resolution of 1000 dpi.
EDIT:
If I unzip the word file and browse to folder word\media I can see all images with the correct pixel size (for this example the expected 2756 x 1757). I'd like to discover if there is a way to retrieve this information from InlineShape object.

Try saving it as "HTML filtered" and you may get to see what Word has actually done internally. I suspect that it has downsampled your huge JPEG to make one that is the right size for the 70x40mm @ 96 dpi that is required and stuffed the original into metadata.  Anything more than 600dpi is beyond most printers resolution.

Thanks @MartinBrown, saving the word file you mean? I agree any how that 600 dpi is enough but scientific papers requires 1000 dpi :(

@MartinBrown, saving as HTML filtered the images are downsampled to the pixel sizes I see in the output of my screen. However if I unzip the word file the stored images are of the right resolution (see EDIT)

I have used LaTeX and EPS vector files for scientific papers. I don't know of a way to access the original images from VBA but I'm aware that they are there. In most instances they are a nuisance when corporate users drag and drop a 12MB ex camera images into Word. Unzipping the document lets you see what's really there in total. It is a long shot but you could try recording a macro and do "save figure as" and cross your fingers. I generally only use VBA in Excel so Word VBA is terra incognito for me.

You can only convert points to pixels if you already know the resolution of the image. The PointsToPixels function in VBA is an old one and dates to when images were stored at 96ppi.
Dependent on which version of Word you are using this may no longer be the case. The resolution of images in the document is determined by a per document setting which, AFAIK, is not available in VBA.

